# put JSON object in thymeleaf with th tag

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

```
th:attr="data-params='{url:\'api/module/appId?appId='+${appId}+'\',dataName:\'module\'}'">
```

data-params  should be a Json Object which i can use JSON.parse().And JSON.parse() needs Json Object like this `{url: "/api/role/app?appId=d73ed474fca942609133b915c5da6d2a", dataName: "role"}`

`th:attr` gets `"{url:'api/module/appId?appId=d73ed474fca942609133b915c5da6d2a',dataName:'module'}"`

Here is the question : how do i suppose to get right Json Object using `th:attr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping double quotes with `&quot;` works for me:

```
<span id="test" th:attr="data-params='{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;api/module/appId?appId='+${appId}+'&quot;,&quot;dataName&quot;:&quot;module&quot;}'" />
```

Testing:

```
<script>
    var json = $('#test').attr("data-params");
    console.log(json);
    console.log(JSON.parse(json));
</script>
```

Both Chrome and Firefox output correctly in their developer logs:

```
{"url":"api/module/appId?appId=null","dataName":"module"}
Object { url: "api/module/appId?appId=null", dataName: "module" }
```